# Download different table columns in csv format using mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, csv

I want to download the different column data from the sql server using mvc3, For instance I want to download 5 columns from table account where id = 1, and 2 columns from products where id =1. Can any one provide me with some tutorial or any links to achieve this . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like

```
public ActionResult ExportCsv(int page, string orderBy, string filter)
        {
            IEnumerable orders = GetOrders().AsQueryable().ToGridModel(page, 10, orderBy, string.Empty, filter).Data;
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.Write("OrderID,");
            writer.Write("ContactName,");
            writer.Write("ShipAddress,");
            writer.Write("OrderDate");
            writer.WriteLine();
            foreach (Order order in orders)
            {
                writer.Write(order.OrderID);
                writer.Write(",");
                writer.Write("\"");
                writer.Write(order.Customer.ContactName);
                writer.Write("\"");
                writer.Write(",");
                writer.Write("\"");
                writer.Write(order.ShipAddress);
                writer.Write("\"");
                writer.Write(",");
                writer.Write(order.OrderDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
                writer.WriteLine();
            }
            writer.Flush();
            output.Position = 0;

            return File(output, "text/comma-separated-values", "Orders.csv");
        }
```

For further detail visit [Telerik Demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customcommand?theme=vista). you do not need to use telerik to implement this feature. just write actionresult, fetch data transform it to csv, call it from your browser and you are done.

Comment: How to write the Entitysql query for it

Comment: loot at http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/natesstuff/archive/2008/11/02/linq-to-entities-example-queries.aspx for example linq to entity queries